# Python convert raw text to Yaml or Json

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab

Is there any way where we can convert raw text yaml formatted data to yaml file or json.
I'm getting a raw file data in response as

```
image: artifactory.test.com/hello:v1
stages:
  - build

build-job-example:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building the 'Hello World' app"
    - python3 --version
  only:
    - main
```

How do I convert it into a yaml, so that I can edit the contents and push to gitlab.
My aim it to replace few values with respect to key and commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yaml.safe_load()`

For instance:

```
import yaml

yml_str = """
image: artifactory.test.com/hello:v1
stages:
  - build

build-job-example:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building the 'Hello World' app"
    - python3 --version
  only:
    - main
"""

yml = yaml.safe_load(yml_str)
print(yml['build-job-example'])
```

Ouput:

```
{'stage': 'build', 'script': ['echo "Building the \'Hello World\' app"', 'python3 --version'], 'only': ['main']}
```